# Prove $f(z) =f(z ̄)$ if $f(z) = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Prove that $f$ of $z $ where $z$ is a complex number is equal to $f$ of $z ̄$ (which is the conjugate of $z$) if $f(z)=0$.
$f(x) =x^2+8x+16$

Edit: $f(z ̄)= z^2+8+16$ with a bar over everything.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what is $\overline{x^2 + 8 x + 16}$?

Comment: Is it the same thing with the macros just flipped, I know I can put the bar over everything for f of z bar.

Comment: By macro I mean the bar above it

Comment: follow up question, can we take the conjugate of both sides?

Comment: So if $f(x)$ is a real number, $f(\overline{x}) = \overline{f(x)} = f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be partially extended. If $f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^m a_j z^j$ is a polynomial of real coefficients, then $f(z)$ is symmetric about the real line, a.k.a. $f(z) = f(\overline z)$.